# How to check the list is null or empty before firstordefault()

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check the `List<Product> _product` outcome is null or empty before `firstordefault()`
here is the code.

```
product = GetDetails(new List<IProduct> { product }, DetailsRS).FirstOrDefault()
```

Can any one suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360179(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: How is `GetDetails` defined?

Comment: It will return the list of product and the return type is IProduct.

Comment: @abhitalks that method clearly states that it will throw a `NullReferenceException` if the source is `null`.

Comment: Ahh yes, my bad. Thanks @MarcGravell. But as an aside, the `defaultifempty` may still be required later as `firstordefault` will return the default of type which could be null reference?

Comment: @abhitalks well, for *that*, the null-coalescing operator is fine; `(blah) ?? whatever`

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't matter much if the list is *empty* - `FirstOrDefault` is perfectly fine with that. The interesting question is whether it is *null*. While we wait for C# 6 (which hopes to offer some voodoo here), we can use:

```
var foo = list == null ? null : list.FirstOrDefault();
```

You could even create a new extension method for this, i.e.

```
var foo = list.NullSafeFirstOrDefault();
```

using:

```
public static T NullSafeFirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
    return source == null ? default(T) : source.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: can you expand on that voodoo?

Answer (score 0):

simplified:

```cs
var foo = list?.FirstOrDefault();
```